# Active Directory (AD) for public SaaS offering?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, saas

We're about to build a new SaaS offering in Azure.

OPTION 1: Use traditional username/password stored (encrypted) in database

Pro: Any user can create an account and immediately start using

Con: Less security and control

OPTION 2: Use Active Directory (AD) for user security and management

Pro: Tighter control of our users and websites; better security

Con: User has to make contact with us to create their account

It's not exactly a SaaS where we'd want it wide open to the public anyway.. each company would have its own database and then a database for each of its franchise locations.  So maybe AD pros outweigh the cons in this scenario?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

*Con: User has to make contact with us to create their account*

This is not necessarily the case. [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) supports user self-service for sign up.

I'd have anticipated that some of your customers would probably like to manage their users using their own AD tenant as well, which is also a supported scenario.

This is quite a deep topic with numerous scenarios supported by Active Directory so I am leaning toward the 'answer' requiring a clear and precise statement of *how* you intend to use AD. Will you manage users in:

- your own tenant?
- federation with a number of your customers' tenants?
- both?
- social logins?

These all need to be worked through and understood to adequately come to a decision.

Comment: Yes, in our own tenant of the offering I believe.  The first user of a company would be the admin for that company and could dole out permissions accordingly.  I was thinking if all the users were in our AD, using AD authentication in all of our Azure subdomain sites would be great for security (as opposed to the traditional way).  Thanks for the feedback.